# Setting highest priority for a filter registered using ServletContextListener

Tags: java, servlet-filters

I have few filters defined in web.xml and another one filter defined through ServletContextListner as below. I want to prioritize the one defined through ServletContextListner in Java as it is the one which will intercept all the request.

```
class myConfigListner implements ServletContextListener {

@Override
public void contextIntialized (ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
   ServletContext svc = servletContextEvent.getServletContext();
   FilterRegistration.Dynamic fr = svc.addFilter("Third Party Filter", ThirdPartyFilter.class);
   fr.addMapingForUrlPatterns(EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST),true,"/*");
   fr.setInitParameter("Param-1 that thirdparty filter expects", "value");
}
}
```

```
web.xml {
// In this web.xml there are other filters, but one of them  has same mapping as the one defined above and it looks this is the one that is taking precedance.  
}
```

I tried `fr.setInitParameter("priority", "1");` in the java class but seems it does not work.